# Макрос в Google таблице. Замена точек на запятые в определенных столбцах

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Работаю с таблицами. Проблема стара как мир - некоторые числа с точкой от исходника конвертируются в дату в Гугл таблицах (1% от общего кол-ва). Номера столбцов известны, весь лист обходить не надо. Нужно просто заменить точку на запятую в этих столбцах (данные все равно идут как число!), но автоматически это не записывается. А каждый раз вручную ну такое себе удовольствие...
В синтаксисе макросов в таблицах пока не сильна. Текущий код просто сортирует столбцы и приводит к числам с двумя знаками после запятой.
Может быть кто-то может поделиться кодом, как реализовать замену символов не на весь лист, а только на диапазон? Спасибо

```js
function PreparationData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H:H').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().moveColumns(spreadsheet.getRange('H:H'), 7);
  spreadsheet.getRange('H:H').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().moveColumns(spreadsheet.getRange('H:H'), 6);
  spreadsheet.getRange('G:I').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0.00'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример функции, которая в столбце `B` (можно указать любой диапазон) заменяет `.` на `,`

```
function replaceDots() {
  var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID"); // Тут ID вашей таблицы
  var sheet = sheetActive.getSheetByName("List_name"); // Тут название листа
  var range = sheet.getRange("B:B"); // Тут диапазон, в котором будет производиться замена
    range.setValues(range.getDisplayValues().map(function(row) {
      return [row[0].toString().replace(".", ",")];
}));
}
```

напишите, если это решит ваш вопрос

Comment: Да, этот код закрыл потребность полностью. Уточнение - мне макрос правда нужен на множество листов, и всегда на каждом листе это будет уже выделенный диапазон столбцов, поэтому перепилила так

function replaceDots() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A:A'); // Тут диапазон A:A, в котором будет производиться замена при уже выделенных столбцах
    range.setValues(range.getDisplayValues().map(function(row) {
      return [row[0].toString().replace(".", ",")];
}));
}

Comment: @SvetlanaA, ну, так отметьте как решение этот ответ. А решение в цикле неверное в принципе. Но если работает, пусть работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант, где замена производится не во всех ячейках диапазона, а только в тех, где найдена точка. Учитывая, что доля точек 1%, должно (теоретически) работать быстро. Поиск производится на всем листе.

```
function PreparationData() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().createTextFinder('.').findAll().forEach(function(cell) {
      cell.setValue(cell.getDisplayValue().toString().replace(".", ","));
    });
}
```

Если область поиска нужно ограничить диапазоном, например, столбцом 'H', можно вызвать метод `createTextFinder('.')` соответствующего диапазона:

```
function PreparationData() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('H:H').createTextFinder('.').findAll().forEach(function(cell) {
      cell.setValue(cell.getDisplayValue().toString().replace(".", ","));
    });
}
```

Comment: createTextFinder очень сильно виснет в скрипте, думаю, это связано с тем, что мы имеем дело изначально с цифрами и датами, и конвертировать в текст нужно до поиска.... Разве что есть какая-то функция вроде isDate в скрипте, которая вернет ячейки с датами под замену